# How to pass variables from parent class to child class?

Tags: python, class

As I know, the typical child class of python might should be:

```py
class Parent:
    """CODE HERE"""

class Child(Parent):
    """CODE HERE"""
```

But this doesn't fit my situation. I would like that, when the variable of parent class changes, the child class changes together. So I have to use:

```py
class Session:
    def __init__(self):
        self.token = 'FoObArFooBar'
        self.api_url = f'https://example.com/post/{self.token}'

    class Post:
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def post(self):
            requests.post(super.api_url)
```

So that when I change `Session.api_url`, the child class `Post` also changes. But I got this error:

```
----> 1 Session.Post.post()

TypeError: post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

So how to pass variables in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Did you actually try to do this with the standard parent-child class arrangement? Because I don't see why what you're describing shouldn't work without resorting to nested classes.

Comment: Are you making sure to instantiate `Session.Post` and call the `post()` method from that object? I suspect you are trying to call it directly from the class itself as `Session.Post.post()`, which would cause the issue.

Comment: Why not just have Session.post()?

Comment: `Post` is a nested class, not a child of `Session`. There is no inheritance here.